# Connecting to remote machine through ssh+mc without using password

Tags: ssh, midnight-commander

while using midnight commander (`mc`) on my pc, I usually `ssh` to a remote server in another continent. I'm not an admin on the server. I already have generated private and public keys in order to connect quickly from the terminal. When I'm using `mc` however, I'm required to write my password every time. This is a bummer, as it is an alphanumeric password, so I have to look for it, copy it and then paste it.

I couldn't find a way to use keys also while requesting the connection through `mc`. Is there a way to `ssh` with keys using `mc`?

thank you in advance

Comment: @waltinator I would suggest you read the question. As far as I can tell the user *has* configured ssh keys correctly, but doesn't' work in mc. [This blog post](https://blog.zmole.ro/how-to-use-your-ssh-key-to-connect-remotely-from-mc-midnight-commander/) indicates that some more magic is needed. I do not know; I've never used `mc`, but from the question things *are* set up.

Comment: I did, in fact, configured the ssh keys correctly and I've been using them for a while. The link you provided seems interesting, I will look into that